# Pandas - How to verify if Series value 1 is in Series value 2 ( at row level)

Tags: python, pandas

Simply put I'm trying to figure out if the string in Series 1 is in Series 2 of the same DataFrame and the same row. From there I would use the True/False values to filter the DataFrame. I tried:
`df['column1'].isin(df['column2'])`.

This partially works but it's not looking only at the same row. It's looking in the entire series and bringing back false positives. The code below achieved what I was attempting to do I just wanted to know if there is code that is more efficient?

```
# Create empty list    
del_filt = []

# Use loop to create a list of True/False values
for i in range(len(df)):
    del_filt.append(df.loc[i, 'Column1'] in df.loc[i, 'Column2'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use numpy and numpy.where() to be specific. Please, take a look at my example below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[1,2,3,4,5],"col2":[1,23,3,44,51]})

df["matched"] = np.where(df["col1"] == df["col2"], "yes", "no")
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2 matched
0     1     1     yes
1     2    23      no
2     3     3     yes
3     4    44      no
4     5    51      no
```

Of course you can replace "yes" and "no" with True and False and anything else you like.

If a partial match is what you are looking for you could use something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":["1","19","3","67","5"],"col2":["1","23","3","44","51"]})

df["matched"] = df.apply(lambda row: all(i in row.col2 for i in row.col1), axis=1)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2  matched
0    1    1     True
1   19   23    False
2    3    3     True
3   67   44    False
4    5   51     True
```

Comment: This is exact match, OP wants partial match.

Comment: @Erfan Edited the answer to account for a partial match as well, although I don't think that OP was looking for that.

Answer (score 0):

Rowwise comparison is a bit different than the vectorized methods we have.

We can use list comprehension with `zip` here:

```
del_filt = [col1 in col2 for col1, col2 in zip(df['Column1'], df['Column2'])
```

Or we can use `DataFrame.apply`:

```
del_filt = df.apply(lambda x: x['Column1'] in x['Column2'], axis=1)
```